# How do I use a user's name, entered in a textbox in MainWindow, in textblocks in several other windows?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, window, textblock

When a user enters his/her name in 'whatsYourNameTextbox' in my MainWindow, I want that name to be used in Textblocks in other windows in my app. I can get it to work for a Textblock in the MainWindow, using this code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        x:Name="doYouWannaPlayTextblock" 
        FontFamily="Segoe Print"
        FontSize="16"
        FontWeight="SemiBold"
        Foreground="Red"
        Padding="20"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        TextAlignment="Center"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0.4,0.2,-25"> 
        Hi,
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=playerNameTextbox}"/>
        - it's good to see you. Would you like to play 'Tables'? If so, just click the 'Choose Game' button.
    </TextBlock>
```

But when I use the same code in the 'ChooseGameWindow' (and, I assume, in other windows I plan to put into the app) the user's name doesn't appear but no error is thrown up. Here's the code in the 'ChooseGameWindow':

```
<TextBlock             
        FontFamily="Segoe Print"
        FontSize="16"
        FontWeight="SemiBold"
        Foreground="Red"
        Padding="20"
        Visibility="Visible"
        TextAlignment="Center"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="293" Height="71"> 
        Hi
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=playerNameTextbox}"/>
        . Click a 'Play Me' button.
    </TextBlock>
```

I'm guessing that I need to reword the binding to refer to something like, 'MainWindow.whatsYourNameTextbox' (or similar) but haven't been able to work out how to do it. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event aggregator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx) to communicate between view models.

**Edit**

```
private void ChooseGameCommandHandler()
{
    var window = new MainWindow();
    window.DataContext = new MyViewModel(TextBoxValue);
    window.Show();
    IsVisible = false;
}
```

[Full sample code here](https://github.com/adpartage/StackOverflow/tree/master/WpfApp1)

Comment: Many thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I'm very much a self-teaching, beginner programmer so, sadly, the 'event aggregator' info contained in your link (and the associated MVVM stuff) is probably going to be way above my current level of expertise. I'll have a go at it but I'm finding even relatively low level stuff really quite complex and difficult to get my head around. Can you suggest anything easier?

Comment: How do you open the other window?(provide some code)

Comment: This is the code I use. It basically makes a textblock (doYouWannaPlayTextblock) and a button (chooseGameButton) visible and when the chooseGameButton is clicked it makes the ChooseGameWindow visible and hides the MainWindow. (edit - hmmm, can't seem to add code).

Comment: private void playerNameTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                doYouWannaPlayTextblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                chooseGameButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void chooseGameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChooseGameWindow ChooseGameWindow = new ChooseGameWindow();
            ChooseGameWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

Comment: Does that help,@adPartage?

Comment: Then it's quit simple I think (as it's not a live refresh of doYouWannaPlayTextBlock). You can pass the value to the constructor of chooseGameWindow's view model.

Comment: Before you go further, I suggest you to train and read more about WPF. The code can be stinky if you don't know the main concept of WPF. This video is a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRxnZahCPFQ

Comment: Thanks for the advice, adPartage - I'll take it on board.